# Does drinking water more than 10 liters per day has any benefit or side effect?

Tags: side-effects, water, benefits, body-temperature

I knew the fact that drinking water more is good for health. 3 Liters per day is good enough for health. But I am drinking more than 10 liters per day. My question is does drinking water more than 10 liters reduce body heat or do I have any side effect for it ?

Comment: Are you asking for the effects of drinking water often or drinking more than 10 litres of water?

Comment: That's a dangerous practice for the reasons Prince described in his answer. I would advise you to stop it immediately and limit yourself to reasonable quantities. 10 liters per day is not at all reasonable.

Comment: @ Prince - I am asking drinking more than 10 liters of water per day.

Comment: I agree with Carey!  Limit yourself, and go see your doctor/NP/PA to evaluate why you are so thirsty (referring to your other posted question about excessive thirst).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drinking the appropriate amount of water is okay, but when it becomes excessive, then it could lead to some dangerous circumstances.

The appropriate amount of water varies according to lifestyle. According to the popular 8 by 8 rule which says that one should drink eight glasses, each consisting of eight ounce of water, may not suit every individual. Says nutritionist Venu Adhiya Hirani, "While the general belief is to drink eight to 10 glasses of water, it is advisable to drink 12 to 15 glasses of fluids which includes water, tea, buttermilk, soup, etc. This would amount to an intake of around 2.5 litres of fluids everyday."

According to Krishnan, If you have a sedentary lifestyle and work in an air-conditioned environment where there is no scope for water loss via sweat, drinking more than 2 to 2.5 litres of water is not advisable. It will end up accumulating in your kidney and cause edema. For moderate workers like salespersons, who are required to do physical activity, it is important to drink around three litres of water.

“It also depends on your size and weight, and also on your activity level and where you live,” Nessler says. “In general, you should try to drink between half an ounce and an ounce of water for each pound you weigh, every day." For example, if you weigh 150 pounds, that would be 75 to 150 ounces of water a day.

http://m.timesofindia.com/life-style/health-fitness/diet/Health-benefits-of-black-tea/articleshow/8508759.cms

**Consequences of drinking excess water**

**1. Causes Hyponatremia:**

The sodium content in the blood influences the functioning of the electrolytes. These electrolytes are responsible for sending signals to the cells which control various operations of the body. When you consume too much water, the sodium levels in the blood decrease. This stops the electrolytes from sending signals to the cells.

**2. Overburdens The Heart:**

The heart performs the vital function of pumping blood through your entire body. When you consume too much of water, this increases the volume of blood inside your body. The increased blood volume causes unnecessary pressure on the blood vessels and the heart, leading to seizure in some cases.

**3. Causes Damage To Glomeruli:**

Glomeruli are capillary beds in our kidneys. They work as a filtering station to excrete excess water from the body. Too much of water can cause potential damage to this system, leading to serious health hazards. The kidneys have to work overtime to process all this unnecessary water that is beyond their normal filtering capacity (1000 ml per hour).

**4. Causes Swelling Of Cells:**

As your blood gets diluted due to excess water, the concentration of electrolytes in the blood becomes lower than that in the cells. To maintain a balance in the concentration of electrolytes in the blood and the cells, water begins to flow into the cells. This results in swelling of cells, which is a dangerous condition.

**5. Causes Brain Edema:**

This is the swelling of brain cells. It is as hazardous as it sounds. Most of the cells in our body have a lot of room to stretch out. But the flat bones in our skull do not leave much space for the brain cells to be accommodated freely. When excess water in the blood vessels starts seeping into the brain cells, it causes swelling in the cells of the brain. This leads to severe conditions that include coma, brainstem herniation, and respiratory attack.

***Note:*** There has even been a [report](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/2262683/Man-dies-after-drinking-10-litres-of-water-in-eight-hours.html) of a man who died drinking 10 litres of water within eight hours.

Comment: You need to consume as much water as you lose it from your body (mainly by urinating and sweating). If you lose 2 liters you need to replace 2 liters and if you lose 6 liters (e.g. when working in a hot environment), you need to replace 6 liters. So, the recommendation about 0.5-1 ounce per pound of body weight is misleading.

Answer (score -1):

If you feel dehydrated it's probably you're just missing natural electrolytes and other nutrients that help with hydration(water retention) so you have to drink alot less and feel hydrated for a long time.

Theres way better methods to reduce body heat,for example,put plenty of water on your body with a rag and get a fan towards you or go in the outdoor wind. That is how the body cools itself off with sweat. Water on skin cools several times ,10-20X more than air itself.

Maybe building a homemade house cooling system(with water),look it up on internet. You can look how to make electricity if you live in a place that is expensive, and then buy a cooling unit,but the homemade one works well it seems.